# multiple barplots in same graph maintain the same axes and same bar width

Tags: r, axes, par, bar-chart

Very stupid question but I can't find the answer online:

Need to plot multiple barplots together like this:

```
 i=1:4
 main = paste ("Location ", i)

 windows()
 par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 a<-table(c(rep(10, 6), rep(4, 32)))
 b<-table(c(rep(9, 6), rep(10, 32), rep(11,4)))
 c<-table(c(rep(10, 6)))
 d<-table(c(rep(10, 3), rep(9, 3), rep(8, 5)))

 barplot(a,  main=main[1], xlab='RSSI')
 barplot(b,  main=main[2], xlab='RSSI')
 barplot(c,  main=main[3], xlab='RSSI')#, width=0.5
 barplot(d,  main=main[4], xlab='RSSI')
```

1) is it possible to maintain constant the axes scale, so that it is the same on every graph?

2) is it possible to maintain constant the bar width in the graphs? I tried with width but it does not seem to work and i would like to have it constant and fixed between graphs.

Thanks

EDIT: for 2) I know you can add zeros, so that all the graphics have the same number of classes involved, but since I am plotting in a for loop that I have removed to make the example simpler, I would rather use another way to do it, if it is possible.
Thanks again

Comment: A small side-note: maybe I have misunderstood you, but wouldn't it be easier to compare the different locations if you had the same classes for each location. Sorry if I am misunderstanding your objectives.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you completely, are you asking why i don't "invert x and y"? If so, I am interested in the local behaviour of the variable that is discrete, checking how the value = 44 behaves spatially compared to value =45 is just not a phenomenon of interest. Did I get your point?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. In your question you wrote you know how to make "all the graphics have the same number of classes involved", but that you removed classes with zero counts in the example. I just thought that perhaps it would be easier to compare counts for different levels of RSSI, among the different locations if you had the same set of classes for each location, i.e. that also RSSI classes with zero counts were included. But again, I might have misunderstood your overall aim. Cheers.

Comment: i meant that i could possibly add zeros to have a better graphical impact, there are no zeros in my dataset, simply the class is not present, thanks for your help, is really appreciated and sorry for my explanation that has been quite poor. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `xlim` and `ylim` argument described in `?barplot`:

```
barplot(a,  main=main[1], xlab='RSSI', xlim=c(0, 4), ylim=c(0, 32))
barplot(b,  main=main[2], xlab='RSSI', xlim=c(0, 4), ylim=c(0, 32))
barplot(c,  main=main[3], xlab='RSSI', xlim=c(0, 4), ylim=c(0, 32))
barplot(d,  main=main[4], xlab='RSSI', xlim=c(0, 4), ylim=c(0, 32))
```

[image]

(`xlim` and `width` influence each other.)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it was only for your example that you kept the data for each plot in separate vectors. Anyway, if the number of locations would be much bigger, you will soon have your workspace cluttered with small vectors, and you would have to call `table`and `barplot` many times.

It would be much easier to work with the data stored in a data frame, regardless if you plot using `base` R functions, or `ggplot`. Furthermore, it might be easier to compare counts for different levels of RSSI, among the different locations, if the same set of classes for each location is used in each plot, i.e. that also RSSI classes with zero counts were included. You might also use the same scale of the y axis across locations. Here is a small example with `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)

# create a data frame with the data in your vectors
# 'x' is the value, and 'loc' the location of each registration
df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(10, 6), rep(4, 32),
                       rep(9, 6), rep(10, 32), rep(11, 4),
                       rep(10, 6),
                       rep(10, 3), rep(9, 3), rep(8, 5)),
                 loc = c(rep("a", 6+32), rep("b", 6+32+4), rep("c", 6), rep("d", 3+3+5)))

# plot using geom_bar, which default counts the cases for each level of  - no need for 'table'
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(x))) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~ loc)
```

[image]

Comment: yes i am using a dataframe, i used the vectors to make the example as readable as possible, i am still struggling with ggplot, so thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Irene, glad to help. When I started with `ggplot`, I found it very useful to work through the examples [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/). Good luck!

Comment: + 1 for the reference